# Bottom Sheet with adapting background

Tags: swiftui

I would like to display a bottom sheet while compressing the view which is in the background. As an experiment I made this example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    @ObservedObject var geopasser = Geo()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("show"){
                show.toggle()
            }
                .offset(y: show ? -geopasser.height * 0.5 : 0)
            Text("Test")
                .offset(y: show ? -geopasser.height * 0.5 : 0)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.green)
        .sheet(isPresented: $show, content: {
            VStack{
                GeometryReader{geo in
                    VStack{
                        geopasser.pass(geo: geo)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Showed \(geo.frame(in: .global).minY)")
                            .presentationDetents([.medium])
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
            }
            .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.4)])
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(
                .enabled(upThrough: .fraction(0.4))
            )
        })
    }
}

class Geo: ObservableObject{
    @Published var height: CGFloat
    init(){
        _height = .init(initialValue: 0)
    }
    
    func pass(geo: GeometryProxy)->EmptyView{
        height = geo.size.height
        return EmptyView()
    }
}
```

In this video https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPaJM.jpg you can see in the console that there is a sort of endless loop when swiping the sheet away.

Is there an other way to achieve the goal to adapt the background view dependent of the sheet position?

Thanks for an answer :)

Comment: If you address the purple warning seen in the video, you should be in a stronger position. Replace `height = geo.size.height` with `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.height = geo.size.height }`